# Is there any way to change the SSIS connection managers while deploying the packages to different environments?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS. Right now when I deploy a package from dev and then to production environment, I used to open the solution using visual studio and then editting the connection managers. Is there any other way for doing this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can create environment variables in your integration service catalog. Use these and then in  your SQL Job you get set which enviroment to use. Then you can manage your connection that way.

Comment: Are you using the SSIS db?

Comment: Here is a guide you can follow: https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables

Comment: I use config files for connection strings and file paths in each environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis method for controlling and allowing to switch connections between `DEV` and `PROD` would be to handle it in `Integration Services Catalog`, under the `SSISDB`.

This allows you to create an enviroment called `DEV` under your `DEV` server and a environment called `PROD` on your `PROD` server. Each difference is that the variables has different connectionstrings, and hereby you never need to edit them into your SSIS project. So basically you can deploy your SSIS project to `PROD` with dev connectionstrings, but the environment will make sure it always points to your `PROD` connections.

Instead of posting 10 pictures i would follow this [guide](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables) which makes your able to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you plaidDK. I tried it and found that it is working. Thanks for the help.